# How can I use correcty the Body-parser middleware

Tags: javascript

I´m new to node.js and I cant start correctly the body-parser middleware.

As tutorials described, I try to instanciate the bodyParsers as a const and after I try to use it in app.use.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const users = [
  {name: 'Jones', email: 'jones@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Henrique', email: 'henrique@hotmail.com'}
]

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/users', (req,res)=> {
  res.send(users);
})

app.post ('/users', (req,res)=>{
 console.log(req.body);
 res.end();
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Rota padrão');
  
  console.log();
  
});


// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
  
});
```

I received this error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem with the middleware? What's the content of the request you're making?

Comment: Its a very simple request: {
    "nome": "Jaime"
    "email": "jaimenasser@outlook.com"
}

Comment: You seem to be missing a comma...

Comment: That´s alright ! Thanks a lot, I was focused on the dependencies stuff, and the problem was the simplest thing.